# Swap Qt Widgets

Tags: c++, qt, polymorphism, swap, qobject

I am running into a problem. I want to swap two Qt widgets:

```
void swap(QMainWindow **w1, QMainWindow **w2)
{
    QMainWindow *w3;

    w3 = *w1;
    *w1 = *w2;
    *w2 = w3;
}
```

However if I have `widget1` of type `MainWindow1*` and `widget2` of type `MainWindow2*` and I call `swap(&widget1, &widget2);` I get

```
/home/user/Test/manager.cpp:24: error: invalid conversion from 'MainWindow1**' to 'QMainWindow**' [-fpermissive]
  swap(&widget1, &widget2);
       ^
```

I must note that `MainWindow1` and `MainWindow2` are two `QMainWindow` derived classes.

My question is: Is it possible to create a function that swaps at runtime two polymorphic objects? How can I get around this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have not used Qt.Does QMainWindow class implements the assignment operator function? If the answer is yes, you can.I suggest you check API

Comment: Note that [std::swap already exists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) in C++ (if you `#include <algorithm>`).  You don't have to write it yourself.  But what you are asking here runs against the static type system principles of C++.  Types of all variables are fixed at compile-time...and that includes pointers.  If you need something that can hold different pointers, you can use a typed union...but that probably means your design is wrong.  You may just need another intermediate base class derived from QMainWindow for whatever these windows have in common.

Comment: @RonTang Unfortunately none of the QObject classes, thus QMainWindow implement the assignment operator or copy constructor. This is by design in Qt. So it is not possible...

Comment: @HostileFork I am aware of `std::swap`, thank you. I just forgot about it in this test application :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be passing `MainWindow1` and `MainWindow2` pointers to swap like below.

```
MainWindow1* w1 = new MainWindow1();
MainWindow2* w2 = new MainWindow2();
swap(&w1, &w2);
```

If swap *could* happen in this case, `MainWindow1` pointer would point to a `MainWindow2` object, which is not right.

You have to pass `MainWindow` pointers to swap like below.

```
MainWindow* w1 = new MainWindow1();
MainWindow* w2 = new MainWindow2();
swap(&w1, &w2);
```